# Introduce a function within my existing keyword detecting script that will recheck the same condition after a predetermined period of time

Tags: bash, shell, awk, centos

I have a script that monitors a log file for a keyword. Once it discovers the keyword it will execute a function (send's email of server down/up status).

*edited
I now desire for the script to report the down status and then attempt to restart the server by calling on a script.

The problem is the keyword im monitoring for can occur when the network is busy or congested. It doesn't happen often and when it does it's not for long and it doesn't necessarily mean the server is down. In short, im attempting to eliminate or otherwise reduce false reports.

I think my best approach is to have the script:

1. monitor for the "server down" keyword (already in script)
2. detect the keyword                    (already in script)
3. pause for a predetermined period of time. Say maybe 5 sec
   The pause is to allow the server to fully go down before a restart is attempted.
4. report the "server down" state (already in script)
5. Issue a command that triggers (restart.sh) script
6. monitor for the "server up" keyword (already in script)
7. detect "server up" state (already in script)
8. report "server up" state (already in script)

So I guess pretty much just need the pause after down state is detected before calling on the restart.sh script

Here's what I have in my script so far:

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/user | /usr/bin/gawk '
    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { report("down") }
    /daemon apps started/  { report("up") }

    function report(curr_state,    msg) {
        if ( prev_state != curr_state ) {
             msg = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S Server is " curr_state
            system("mail -s \047" msg "\047 mail@gmail.com </dev/null")
            print msg | "cat>&2"
            print strftime(msg) | "tee -a \047/var/log/server_mon.txt\047 >&2"
            prev_state = curr_state
        }
    }
```

So I guess pretty much just need the pause after down state is reported before calling on the restart.sh script and next awaiting the up state before reporting up. if up never happens I still have the notification from the original down.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. I'm assuming/hoping there are timestamps in your log file so we can use those to calculate whether or not that 5 second interval passed between errors.

Comment: Hmm, I see we've already had this conversation - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56193943/1745001. so you have timestamps in your log file - just use them.

Comment: Hang on - shouldn't your logic be that if you get "down" and 5 secs passes without getting an "up" then you should report it? That's different from having to get a second "down" within 5 secs. Or is your monitor script that's producing the log file guaranteed to generate either an "up" or "down" report every 5 secs or less?

Comment: @EdMorton You're absolutely right.. let me edit the post. Good catch

Comment: Actually... I  need to rethink this because with the current logic in place, the script won't be able to detect an "up status" because the server never technically wen't down and therefore will not produce the keyword for up. It's almost like I need some kind of keyword for a baseline status.

Comment: Ok, I just checked and the script that restarts the server actually checks for processes that are already running which means it won't harm the system if I issue a "start server" command while the server is already started. I'm going to reformulate my question to a simpler way (albeit more barbaric way) to get the desired result

Comment: So far ive been able to get a desirable result by adding the following: ; system( "/home/restart.sh") } ----after-----r /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { report("down") }. I would like to see a time delay somewhere in there but it's progress :) gonna keep adding to this till I figure out a solution

Comment: OK, add some sample input and expected output if you'd like help.